# How to explain public key encryption to non-programmers?

Tags: public-key-encryption

Apologies as this is a bit borderline (off topic) but I think a solution will only come from someone who intimately understands the principles of public key encryption and not just the theory.

A few of my colleagues have to explain public key encryption to students who are not really interested in how it works (technicians, Web developers etc.).  They just need to know when and how to use it.  Unfortunately to pass the course the students must grasp the basics at least.  They do but it is never enjoyable.

We have tried to come up with a way to represent public key encryption practically.  Our best effort was a lockable box/cabinet with two keys/combinations which allowed one student to put something in and one to remove it but we couldn't quite make that work.

I personally would love a way to actually and manually encode something in a way which suggests public key encryption and the way it works but I am nowhere near capable of thinking it through.  A hands-on mechanical device is obviously the easiest for non-programmers to understand.  We are open.

Anyone out there got a solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could see the public key as a padlock and the private key as the real key that opens it: Alice gets a padlock from Bob, use it to lock a box with a message for Bob; when Bob receives the box can open it with his own key.

Comment: That's the half I get!  Unfortunately I can't see how to show the private key encryption by the key owner.  My understanding is that this is used purely for authentication of the sender but how can that be illustrated physically - the owner encrypts/locks but anyone can unencrypt if they have the public key.

Comment: that's right, but it used for this purpose: usually people uses private key to sign a digital document in order to prove that the owner "approves" it: using the same analogy you know that if you can open that box then the real sender closes it.